# What does this picture describe?

Tags: router

What does this picture describe?

[image]

Fa0/0 == Fast Ethernet port 0/0.

Fa0/1 == Fast Ethernet port 0/1.

192.168.1.0/24 == IP Address of the PC of the bottom left.

192.168.2.0/24 == IP Address of the PC of the bottom right.

192.168.0.0/24 == Why is there only one IP Address between the routers?

.1,  .2 == What are these values? Are they fractions or what?

S 0/0/0 == What does it mean? 0/0 port of Slot 0? Then why does 0/0 port of Slot 1 is written as 0/1/0?

DTE == Terminal?

DCE == Modem?

Why are 'Terminal' and 'Modem' information necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Fa0/0` is the FastEthernet interface on slot 0, port 0.

`Fa0/1` is the FastEthernet interface on slot 0, port 1.

The addresses `192.168.1.0/24`, `192.168.0.0/24`, and `162.168.2.0/24` are address prefixes representing the subnets used on the respective link.

The `.1` and `.2` mean the specific addresses on that subnet (e.g. the `.1` on the `192.168.1.0/24` subnet means the `192.168.1.1` address).

`S0/0/0` means the serial interface on slot 0, card 0, port 0.

`DTE` means Data Terminal Equipment and `DCE` means Data Communications Equipment. Basically, serving the same purpose as male and female connectors; male connects to female, not another male. The DTE/DCE information is necessary for the configuration of the interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

DCE=ISP
DTE=customer side

they operate off of different standards which are not commonly used in many environments anymore.

Setting the bandwidth and clockrate for this type of setup is necessary and must match on both sides of the link if im not mistaken.

X25 and HDLC are common for this type of setup...the 192.168.0.0 represents the network link of the serial connection between the two routers

.1 and .2 are equal to the last octet in the 192.168.0.x network (class c) and are on the same subnet. Both of these are private IP addresses not routable on the internet.

S0/0/0/0 refers to serial links in routers in Cisco hardware, Serial links are commonly used for connections to ISP at network boundaries or to WAN links of an ISP.

Answer (score 0):

Actual format is Interface card/slot/port numberes

Some devices (like 2500's) it's just a port number (Serial0)

In modular devices, you may have a slot/port number (Serial 0/0)

In larger modular devices, you'll get card/slot/port numberes (Serial 0/0/0)

Answer (score 0):

Fa0/0 --> slot 0, port 0

Fa0/1 --> slot 0, port 1

S0/0/0 --> slot 0, card 0, port 0

DTE --> Data Terminal Equipment
DCE --> Data Communications Equipment

Comment: Please try to give more details, like in the accepted answer. The person asking the question may not understand well what is a slot, a port, etc.